# Invalid operands to binary expression after using vector function C++

Tags: c++

There seems to be an issue trying to create a string vector function linking with the header file and main function. I successfully ran another string function with the same main, header, and function file.

Please keep in mind that I am a C++ beginner and I have been looking for a solution on other posts for an hour. Any suggestions on my code are appreciated as well.

Header:

```
#ifndef splitter
#define splitter

#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cctype>
using std::cout;using std::endl;using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<string> split (const string &s, char separator=' ');

#endif
```

Main:

```
#include"functions.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;using std::endl;using std::cin;
#include<string>
using std::string;
#include<vector>
using std::vector;

int main() {

cout << split("test", 'a') << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Functions:

```
#include "functions.h"

#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;using std::endl;using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<string> split(const string &s, char separator) {
    vector<string> thing;
    thing.push_back(s);
    return thing;
}
```

My error message:

Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'vector' (aka 'vector, allocator > >'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function to insert a `std::vector<std::string>` to `cout`. Hence the line

```
cout << split("test", 'a') << endl;
```

is a problem. Change it to:

```
auto res = split("test", 'a');
for ( auto const& item : res )
{
   std::cout << item << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any sources as a recommendation where I can find information on vectors and other abstract concepts for c++?

Comment: @Dracep, you can pick any beginner level book from this [highly recommended list of good textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).